# SQL python Connection issue

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to pull data from SQL server, I am able to pull the sample data ( up to top 1000 records) but when I run it for all records I get following error:

> ('01000', '[01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
> Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionWrite (send()). (10054) (SQLGetData);
> [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]General network
> error. Check your network documentation. (11)')

I am using following syntax

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=g8w00761s.inc.hpicorp.net;'
                      'Database=ContraDigital2.0;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

sql_query = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT top 1000 * FROM [ContraDigital2.0].[dbo].[contra_anomaly_upfront_backend_1]""",conn)
print(sql_query)
```

Comment: from my experience, driver have this name `SQL Server Native Client X.Y` (X.Y correspond to the SQL version). You can try to connect to your database via odbc to test it

Comment: I am able to connect SQL data base directly but facing problem with Python that too when I want full table, code is working fine for Tp 100, 1000 etc                                           I don't know much about SQL connection so not clear about your suggestion, Could you please elaborate a bit more

Comment: Which version of sql server do you have? List of driver's name can be found [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows)

Comment: @DonKnacki - The "SQL Server Native Client" drivers are older versions, though not as old as the ancient "SQL Server" driver that ships with Windows. The current version of the driver is "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server".

Comment: @Gord Thompson : yes you are right. I often use 2012 version. I share a link where all driver are listed

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, will try these for time being I am trying to submit the code on server itself

Comment: @Ashish, Did you find any solution for this problem ?