# sqlalchemy infrequent errors while running on Virtual Machine

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, virtual-machine

I have a python script that was created to download information on a SQL server, analyze and parse info, then post summary info onto a second SQL server.

In development on my own computer, everything works fine and is very repeatable.  However, the code was hosted onto a virtual machine for daily automation and I've had troubles getting the script to run consistently.  Every couple of times the script runs I'll get a mix of network errors, either related to a read or write issue:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: pyodbc.Error: ('01000', '[01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionRead (recv()). (65534) (SQLEndTran); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]General network error. Check your network documentation. (11)')
```

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', '[01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionWrite (send()). (10054) (SQLGetData); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]General network error. Check your network documentation. (11)')
(Background on this error at httpssqlalche.mee14dbapi)
```

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', '[01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionRead (recv()). (65534) (SQLEndTran); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]General network error. Check your network documentation. (11)')
```

I'm a bit stumped as to why this works just fine on my on computer but not on the VM - except for the fact that sometimes it works fine.  The inconsistency of the issue has been making it difficult to track down. Any suggestions of where to go to try and troubleshoot further?

I've tried increasing timeouts on the connection from SQLAlchemy, checking firewall permissions.

```
db.create_engine(connectionstring + 'driver=SQL+Server', fast_executemany=True, connect_args={'connect_timeout': 1000, 'Remote Query Timeout': 1000, 'statement_timeout': 1000})
```

Edit: Changed the engine creation to specify the same driver between my computer and VM and received the following error instead:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.\r\n (10060) (SQLExecDirectW); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (10060)')
```

Comment: I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67635094/sql-python-connection-issue) where one of the commenters posts a link to [various versions of SQL Server ODBC driver](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows). Maybe a version mismatch is part of the issue?

Comment: it appears to be an intermittent network error. I have experienced this kind of thing before...  one solution is to check and make sure that the connection is open every now and again...

Comment: @Sparrow1029 - thank you for the suggestion.  I changed the engine specification to make sure both are using 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' and started seeing a different error message:  "pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.\r\n (10060) (SQLExecDirectW); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (10060)')"